# sending multiple files by mail in linux

Tags: sendmail

I have many files every day like below, it's 2 diffrence type one of them is "ExtendedStatistic" and another one is "System"

```
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       2018 Apr 19 10:00 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_System.20150419_0900.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       1601 Apr 19 10:00 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_ExtendedStatistic.20150419_0900.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       1973 Apr 19 10:55 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_ExtendedStatistic.20150419_1000.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       2018 Apr 19 11:00 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_System.20150419_1000.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       1353 Apr 19 11:45 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_ExtendedStatistic.20150419_1100.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       2018 Apr 19 12:00 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_System.20150419_1100.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff        981 Apr 19 12:50 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_ExtendedStatistic.20150419_1200.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       2018 Apr 19 13:00 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_System.20150419_1200.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff        857 Apr 19 13:50 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_ExtendedStatistic.20150419_1300.stat
-rw-r-----   1 sdpuser  staff       2018 Apr 19 14:00 tbsdp01a_PSC-TrafficHandler_8.1_A_1_System.20150419_1300.stat
```

my question is how can I create a script to send those files every day at 12:00 AM by mail to my email.
Also, the file type is stat how can I change it to xlsx at the same time?

Comment: Dear Braiam,
yes it's not not free,the problem is i'm not good enogh to write a scripts!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command

```
$ echo "Email Body Content" | mutt -a "file1.xlsx" "file2.xlsx" -s "Mail Subject" -- test@domain.com
```

if mutt is not installed. Please try below command and then try above command

sudo apt-get install mutt

Answer (score -1):

### Use [mailx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx):

The only problem is gathering the attachments with the `-a` option for the [`mailx`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx) command.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.stat; do
    cp ${file} ${file%.stat}.xlsx # you can mv if you prefer.
    attachments="-a ${file%.stat}.xlsx ${attachments}"
done

echo "body" | mailx ${attachments} -s "subject" my.mail@wherever.com
```

This can also be done with the [`mutt`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/man_page.html) command (note that its flags are different).

- To run this every XXX time units you can create a [cron job](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/).

Comment: Thanks Dear Arnon i'll try your Script after i create a cron job :)

Comment: @Mariwan - np. :) please accept the answer (tick it) if you find it helpful once you've tried it.

Comment: This has multiple portability issues and will break on file names which contain whitespace or shell metacharacters.